# Разница между internal и public в c#

Tags: c#, терминология

Может вопрос и глупый но хочу разобраться досконально. Читаю msdn, цитата :

> Модификатор internal делает класс, интерфейс или член видимым только в текущем пакете. Код за пределами текущего пакета не может получить доступ к членам с модификатором internal.

Сразу вопрос что понимается под словом пакет?

Далее:

> В глобальной области действия модификатор internal эквивалентен модификатору public.

Тогда зачем нужны internal если public ему эквивалентен ? Поясните разницу.

Comment: а это откуда конкретно цитата? в msdn вряд ли употребили _пакет_, скорее было бы _сборка_ (_assembly_)

Comment: @Grundy самое смешное, что это действительно из MSDN (оригинал https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ah1b9xxb(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @rdorn, в новой [документации пофиксили](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пакет в данном случае обозначает сборку (Assembly). Грубо говоря - это ваш проект. Т.е. класс, помеченный этим модификатором будет виден из кода сборки (из файлов, относящихся к одному проекту и *тому же пространству имён* - `.csproj`). 
Кроме того, согласно комментарию @andreycha такой класс будет виден для всех дружественных сборок (*friendly assemblies*).

Comment: а отличия от  public тогда в чем?

Comment: @Сергей public виден всем, без ограничений, internal виден всем, но только внутри сборки, в которую входит

Comment: ...а так же все тем сборкам, которые указаны в атрибуте [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: как я понимаю предпочтительней использовать internal ?

Comment: @Сергей предпочтительней для чего? с тем же успехом можно сказать, что предпочтительней использовать private, он же еще больше ограничен

Comment: Зависит от того, кому вы хотите дать доступ к классу. Для классов, относящихся к публичному API Вашей сборки `internal` использовать не следует. А для классов, логика которых предполагает использование только внутри самой сборки (и дружественных ей сборок), логично, конечно же, использовать `internal`.